# CSS - how to code the left column gets narrower when resizing the window?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to make..

```
    header
```

left | middle | right

```
    footer
```

this kind of typical layout using css.
However, when resizing the window smaller it should be something like the following.

```
header
```

middle | right

```
footer
```

width minimum width of something like 1000px... 
You notice that the left column is completely invisible while
the middle part's width should be always the same.
I tried fluid one... fixed one... but no luck so far.
How can this be done?

Sample website: http://vanchosun.com

Thank you, heroes!!

Comment: i don't think you can do this with just css, you'll have to use jQuery or the like to measure screen width, and hide the left column accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my above comment, I don't think it can be done with CSS only.

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/e4jYJ/) more or less what you need?

Comment: I could do it using fluid-fixed-fixed pattern. However, I still thank you a lot for the answer :) I will leave a URL link here in case someone like me wants to do the same thing :: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-34-fluid-fixed-fixed/